# GLM R vs. Python

Tags: python, r, regression, logistic-regression

I am attempting to generate a logistic regression in Python that produces the same results as R. It seems close, but not the same. I made up the following example to illustrate that a difference exists. The data is not real.

R

```
# RStudio 1.1.453

d <- data.frame(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0))

colnames(d) <- c("v1", "v2", "v3")

model <- glm(v1 ~ v2,
         data = d,
         family = "binomial")


summary(model)
```

R Output

```
Call:
glm(formula = v1 ~ v2, family = "binomial", data = d)

Deviance Residuals: 
       1         2         3         4         5  
-1.66511  -0.00013   0.75853   0.75853   0.75853  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    1.099      1.155   0.951    0.341
v2           -19.665   6522.639  -0.003    0.998

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 6.7301  on 4  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4.4987  on 3  degrees of freedom
AIC: 8.4987

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 17
```

Python

```
# Python 3.7.1

import pandas as pd # 0.23.4
import statsmodels.api as sm # 0.9.0
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf # 0.9.0

d = pd.DataFrame({"v1" : [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                  "v2" : [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                  "v3" : [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]})

model = smf.glm(formula = "v1 ~ v2",
               family=sm.families.Binomial(link = sm.genmod.families.links.logit),
               data=d
               ).fit()

model.summary()
```

Python Output

```
                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                     v1   No. Observations:                    5
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                        3
Model Family:                Binomial   Df Model:                            1
Link Function:                  logit   Scale:                          1.0000
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:                -2.2493
Date:                Wed, 07 Nov 2018   Deviance:                       4.4987
Time:                        15:17:52   Pearson chi2:                     4.00
No. Iterations:                    19   Covariance Type:             nonrobust
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept      1.0986      1.155      0.951      0.341      -1.165       3.362
v2           -21.6647   1.77e+04     -0.001      0.999   -3.48e+04    3.47e+04
==============================================================================
```

There is a difference in the number of iterations. From what I can tell, there is some convergence method which may be different between the two, but I don't understand. Is there some other setting I might be missing?

Comment: Given you've only got five data points and only one non-zero value in v2 I'm surprised both systems don't scream some kind of error. There's not a lot of information there. If you do it with a bigger data set with a bit more data you'll find there's close, if not perfect, agreement.

Comment: You have small enough data that you can just compute the log-likelihood by hand and look at it yourself. Here's a graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2vnvch2akx . Estimating the maximum for that function doesn't converge the same because the graph flattens out pretty quickly as you go left, but keeps increasing. They have different ideas of when to stop. The fact that the SE is so large means the log-likelihood is almost completely flat in that region, which hints at the convergence problem.

Comment: I was doing it on a larger dataset of my own, but made this up just to make it verifiable. Results were still fairly far off, especially when comparing to multiple variables.

Comment: Same idea, curvature of the log-likelihood and standard-error are inversely related, so if you see an estimate with a high standard error, that means the likelihood function around that area is very flat, meaning even slight differences in a convergence cutoff will yield very different estimates. In any case, the estimates won't be reliable so you shouldn't be using them.

Comment: This is one of the few times where SAS outperforms R and Python. Just tried running this in SAS with PROC LOGISTIC and got the correct warning: "Model Convergence Status: 
Quasi-complete separation of data points detected. The maximum likelihood estimate may not exist. " (and as you can see in the graph, there function indeed has no maximum). For "What is Quasi-Complete separation?" see https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-complete-or-quasi-complete-separation-in-logisticprobit-regression-and-how-do-we-deal-with-them/

Answer (score 2):

at a guess they have different tradeoffs with regard to numerical stability.

the variance of the `v2` estimate is enormous which is probably causing them both to struggle…  I'd say they've basically given the same answer, at least to the limits available with double precision arithmetic.

the R implementation allows you to pass a `control` parameter:

```
> options(digits=12)
> model <- glm(v1 ~ v2, data=d, family="binomial", control=list(trace=T))
Deviance = 4.67724333758 Iterations - 1
Deviance = 4.5570420311 Iterations - 2
Deviance = 4.51971688994 Iterations - 3
Deviance = 4.50636401333 Iterations - 4
Deviance = 4.50150009179 Iterations - 5
Deviance = 4.49971718523 Iterations - 6
Deviance = 4.49906215541 Iterations - 7
Deviance = 4.49882130019 Iterations - 8
Deviance = 4.4987327103 Iterations - 9
Deviance = 4.49870012203 Iterations - 10
Deviance = 4.49868813377 Iterations - 11
Deviance = 4.49868372357 Iterations - 12
Deviance = 4.49868210116 Iterations - 13
Deviance = 4.4986815043 Iterations - 14
Deviance = 4.49868128473 Iterations - 15
Deviance = 4.49868120396 Iterations - 16
Deviance = 4.49868117424 Iterations - 17
```

which displays its convergence, but I couldn't find anything similar in the Python code.

seeing the above output suggests that they could also be using different cutoffs to determine convergence; R uses [`epsilon = 1e-8`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.control.html)

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I should have clarified that I just made the data up. I was struggling due to ignorance in R to make identical large datasets in python and R, but saw similar results on the real data that I am using.

Comment: different implementations will (almost) always give different results, the difference in the `v2` estimates above are <0.1% of the (estimated) standard deviation.  what do you mean by "similar results on the real data "

Comment: Seems reasonable. I had roughly 80K rows and was seeing intercepts that were 50%+ different. I'm very open to the possibility that I was interpreting them incorrectly. I'll try to reproduce my example with larger data that represents my own.

Comment: you want to be comparing coefficient estimates and their standard errors.  I'd only expect this effect to be noticeable for coefficients with z-scores near 0 / p-values near 1