Why are R and Python giving me different confidence intervals in a logistic model?
I'm making a logistic model predicting whether individuals' health (0=good, 1=poor) is affected by whether they're exposed to secondhand smoke and a few other demographic factors. In R, the code I run to generate the model is (variables renamed to indicate their type):
shs_health_model <- glm(health_binary ~ continuous1 + continuous2 +
                          continuous3 + binary1 + binary2 + 
                          binary3 + binary_smoke, data=mydata, family="binomial")

In Python, my collaborator ran a model with the same variables and dataset using the Logit function from statsmodels.api:
model = sm.Logit(y, X).fit()

To get odds ratios, confidence intervals, and p-values from the data, we ran this code in R:
shs_coef <- exp(cbind(OR = coef(shs_health_model), confint(shs_health_model)))
cbind(shs_coef, P = summary(shs_health_model$coefficients[,'Pr(>|z|)'])

And this code in Python:
odds_ratios = np.exp(model.params)
        conf = np.exp(model.conf_int())
        p_values = model.pvalues
        logistic_results['total_environ_index_cat'] = pd.DataFrame({
            'Odds Ratios': odds_ratios,
            'Confidence Intervals (Lower)': conf[0],
            'Confidence Intervals (Upper)': conf[1],
            'p-values': p_values
        })

The results are overall quite similar.
First, here is the R output:



var
OR
2.5 %
97.5 %
P




(Intercept)
4.3165924
0.40965543
56.1120993
0.239687729


continuous1
1.0351381
0.99352565
1.0799027
0.101217153


continuous2
0.5532695
0.31446430
0.9486117
0.032469282


continuous3
0.9718181
0.92737903
1.0195214
0.231590917


binary1
6.8387667
1.23306396
41.0086896
0.027803143


binary2
0.1796848
0.05899218
0.4867787
0.001274915


binary3
0.6038520
0.16843900
1.8854196
0.405517065


binary_smoke
0.5601202
0.14253453
2.4350002
0.412941761



Then, here's the Python output (as you can see, the confidence interval values are different for some variables while the OR and p values are the same as R's output):




OR
CI(low)
CI(high)
p




const
4.317
0.377
49.42
0.24


continuous1
1.035
0.993
1.079
0.101


continuous2
0.553
0.322
0.952
0.032


continuous3
0.972
0.927
1.018
0.232


binary1
6.839
1.233
37.918
0.028


binary2
0.18
0.063
0.511
0.001


binary3
0.604
0.184
1.982
0.406


binary_smoke
0.56
0.14
2.243
0.413



Could anyone explain/hazard a guess as to why the outputs are different? It's not like one of the outputs consistently has wider confidence intervals than the other, and as far as I'm aware they're both calculating a 95% confidence interval.
Thank you!

Perhaps related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198033/glm-r-vs-python

R uses the likelihood profile for the CIs, while I think that Python uses the asymptotic normal approximation (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.conf_int.html#statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.conf_int).

I think @Axeman is right. If you apply stats:::confint.default() rather than confint() (which by default will call stats:::confint.glm()) you should get the Wald (==asymptotic normal) rather than the profile CIs.
